gdiScaling : issues with lines drawn with GDI
I have enabled the "gdiScaling" option in the manifest to enable the enhanced GDI scaling feature on my MFC C++ application.
I have however some issues with drawing lines with MoveTo/LineTo : drawing a simple rectangle have some "glitches" on the edges, that do not match anymore, like an off-by-one pixel because of the scaling.
Anyone have experienced this? How to fix it? (apart from changing API, for example Rectangle())
PS: gdiScalign is enabled as described in https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/
SelectObject(hdc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, 0));

int x1 = 100;
int y1 = 100;
int x2 = 199;
int y2 = 199;
int ofs = 1;  // LineTo does not include last pixel!

MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x2 + ofs, y1);

MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x1, y2 + ofs);

MoveToEx(hdc, x2, y1, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x2, y2 + ofs);

MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y2, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x2 + ofs, y2);



Can you share the manifest change you are referring to?

see https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/
asmv3:application
<asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/
WindowsSettings">
true
</asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>

I can't repro this. But your question could be improved if you get more specific about how you embedded the manifest into the EXE.  (i.e. what do I need to do to get my Visual C++ project to include your manifest)?

Ok - I got a repro now.

The line-width doubles, now the line end-cap plays a role.  Try using PS_ENDCAP_FLAT.

Tried with LOGBRUSH lb = { BS_SOLID , 0, 0 }; SelectObject(hdc, ExtCreatePen(PS_GEOMETRIC|PS_SOLID|PS_ENDCAP_FLAT, 1, &lb, 0, nullptr)); with no luck, same result.

Forget the manifest thing I suggested in my previous answer.
Thinking like how Windows deals with the "1 past" thing in its drawing APIs and how its intended so that developers shouldn't have to explicitly think about it. My hypothesis is that if you wrote the code to explicitly have each "MoveTo" coordinate pick up explicitly where it was drawn too for the subsequent line, it becomes a lot easier. That is, draw it like your pencil never gets picked up until the entire shape is drawn
So instead of this:
MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x2 + ofs, y1);

MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x1, y2 + ofs);

MoveToEx(hdc, x2, y1, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x2, y2 + ofs);

MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y2, nullptr);
LineTo(hdc, x2 + ofs, y2);


This:
POINT points[] = { POINT{x1,y1}, POINT{x2,y1}, POINT{x2,y2}, POINT{x1,y2}, POINT{x1,y1} };

for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(points)/sizeof(points[0]); i++)
{
    MoveToEx(hdc, points[i - 1].x, points[i - 1].y, nullptr);
    LineTo(hdc, points[i].x, points[i].y);
}

And that might be a correct hypothesis. This is the end result with gdiscaling enabled.

There might be an aliasing issue where the loop closes, but it's technically complete and far better than the original version you had.


I know how to fix this SPECIFIC code to get a correct rectangle, but this is not the point of this issue...
I think it is not correct that THIS SAME CODE gets a different rendering using gdiScaling with respect to native 100% DPI, or even "old" automatic GDI scaling, that is blurry but correct.
If I have to change ALL of my code, I will switch to explicit DPI awareness: but in this case gdiScaling is so useless.

I'm sorry I was unable to help. Sometimes trying some known workarounds that apply to other coding situations work for others. This was probably not one of those cases.  But I'm still happy to try. Can you speak to what you are really trying to do. It sounds like you have a non-DPI aware app, but need to render something in a different DPI. If you can elaborate on that, I can make some additional suggestions.

That is, it sounds like you're ok with regular windows scaling as non DPI aware apps, but there's a specific drawing operation you want higher resolution on. There are some mixed DPI scenarios where your can remain non-dpi aware, but a specific window or thread can temporarily be aware.  That's too much to suggest without more details from you.

Temporarily soved by disabling the whole dpiScaling of this application, too many issues...
